# SQL Select the names of all products orders by customers with the name John only using 1-day shipping

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are the tables in my database.

– Price (**prodID**, from, price)

– Product (**prodID**, name, quantity)

– PO (**prodID, orderID**, amount)

– Order (**orderID**, date, address, status, trackingNumber, custID, shipID)

– Shipping (**shipID**, company, time, price)

– Customer (**custID**, name)

– Address (**addrID**, custID, address)

My code is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer, Shipping
WHERE name like 'John%' and "time" = 1;
```

This returns entries with John as the name or time = 1, instead of entries with both. This also does not return the entries as names of products.

Comment: Could you please provide the code of your attempt and we'll see where you're going wrong. we're not here to do your homework.

Comment: I apologize I'm new to stack overflow. Here is my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from Customer C
inner join Order O
  on O.custID = C.custID 
inner join Shipping S
  on S.shipID = O.shipID
where C.Name like 'John%' and S.Time = '1'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, how would I return that as name of the product ordered by John using 1 day shipping?

Answer (score 0):

You also try this

> SELECT * FROM Customer C INNER JOIN Order O ON O.custID = C.custID
>   INNER JOIN Shipping S ON S.shipID = O.shipID WHERE C.Name like 'John%'
>   AND S.Time = '1' ORDER BY C.Name

---